# Round DateTime to closest quarter hour

Tags: php

How can I round a DateTime object to the closest quarter hour?

So: 2011-05-30 09:11:00 will be rounded to 2011-05-30 09:15:00, 2011-05-30 09:47:00 will be rounded to 2011-05-30 09:45:00 and so on.

Comment: Function for arbitrarily rounding PHP DateTimes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399274/339440

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could extract the minutes divide them by 15, round them and multiply them by 15 again.
Something like

```
// round the "minutes"
$quarter = round(date('i', $yourdate) / 15) * 15;
// get the new timestamp
$roundeddate = mktime(date("H",$yourdate), $quarter, date("s",$yourdate), date("n",$yourdate), date("j",$yourdate), date("Y",$yourdate));
```

Answer (score 2):

This will make problem too, if it's rounding a minute greater that 57.

Try this

```
$current_date_time = '2014-04-14 00:58:01' ;

$current_date_time = round(strtotime($current_date_time) / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60);

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_date_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in my code. There may be more elegant/efficient ways but this appears to work.

```
 // remove seconds from the datetime (we add them back later)
    $seconds = $preset_date->format("s");
    $preset_date->sub(new DateInterval("PT". $seconds ."S"));

    // grab the minutes
    $minutes = $preset_date->format("i");

    // add in the seconds as a fraction of a minute
    $minutes = $minutes + ($seconds/60);

    // get the mod of the minutes
    $minutes = $minutes % 15;

    // if the mod is greater than half way then
    // add enough minutes to make it to the next quarter hour
    if($minutes >= 7.5){
        // round up
        $diff = 15 - $minutes;
        $preset_date->add(new DateInterval("PT".$diff."M"));
    }else{
        // we are less than halfway so round down to previous quarter
        $preset_date->sub(new DateInterval("PT".$minutes."M"));
    }
```