# PHP DateTime round up to nearest 10 minutes

Tags: php, datetime

I'm retrieving a datetime from a mysql field but I need to round it **up** to the nearest 10 minutes.

For example, If the datetime is 2013-11-06 14:00:01, I'd like to return the time as 6/11/2013 14:10.

What's the easiest way to do this?

```
$datetime = new DateTime($mysqldata);

echo $datetime->format('d/m/Y G:i');
```

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Function for arbitrarily rounding PHP DateTimes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399274/339440

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1) Set number of seconds to 0 if necessary (by rounding up to the nearest minute)

```
$second = $datetime->format("s");
if($second > 0)
    $datetime->add(new DateInterval("PT".(60-$second)."S"));
```

2) Get minute

```
$minute = $datetime->format("i");
```

3) Convert modulo 10

```
$minute = $minute % 10;
```

4) Count minutes to next 10-multiple minutes if necessary

```
if($minute != 0)
{
    // Count difference
    $diff = 10 - $minute;
    // Add difference
    $datetime->add(new DateInterval("PT".$diff."M"));
}
```

**Edited, thanks @Ondrej Henek and @berturion**

Comment: It's not precise when the time is already divisible by 10 minutes or when it's 0 seconds. It adds 10 minutes or 60 seconds respectively, therefore it's not dependable. There is an improved version below.

Comment: Thanks, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 18):

I stumbled upon this question and wondered why all the solutions are so complicated. It's simply this:

```
function roundToNext10Min(\DateTime $dt, $precision = 10) {
    $s = $precision * 60;
    $dt->setTimestamp($s * (int) ceil($dt->getTimestamp() / $s));
    return $dt;
}

$dt = roundToNext10Min(new DateTime($str));
echo $dt->format('d/m/Y G:i');
```

Comment: Undefined variable: str

Answer (score 17):

Edit: I wrote this answer a long time ago, some folks discovered that milliseconds are not considered. It is worth try other answers than mine to find the perfect time rounding method.

The answer of @rand have a bug when the DateTime we want to round is already a 10-minutes multiple. It will jump to 10 minutes later while it is not wanted.

Also, always jumping to the next minute with `($datetime->add(new \DateInterval("PT".(60-$second)."S"));` is not wanted when seconds is at zero already.

This enhanced function fixes these bugs and takes a $precision parameter to cover more use cases.

```
function roundTime(\DateTime &$datetime, $precision = 30, $round_lower = false) {
    // 1) Set number of seconds to 0 (by rounding up to the nearest minute if necessary)
    $second = (int) $datetime->format("s");
    if ($second > 30 && $round_lower == false) {
        // Jumps to the next minute
        $datetime->add(new \DateInterval("PT".(60-$second)."S"));
    } elseif ($second > 0) {
        // Back to 0 seconds on current minute
        $datetime->sub(new \DateInterval("PT".$second."S"));
    }
    // 2) Get minute
    $minute = (int) $datetime->format("i");
    // 3) Convert modulo $precision
    $minute = $minute % $precision;
    if ($minute > 0) {
        if($round_lower) {
            $datetime->sub(new \DateInterval("PT".$minute."M"));
        } else {
            // 4) Count minutes to next $precision-multiple minutes
            $diff = $precision - $minute;
            // 5) Add the difference to the original date time
            $datetime->add(new \DateInterval("PT".$diff."M"));
        }
    }
}
```

This function is now perfect for my use and probably for other folks.

**Edit**: Now it allows to set round upper or lower

Comment: Tried it and @berturion is right. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't round microseconds, so rounding close datetimes to see if they equal each other won't work.

Comment: Can somebody please explain to me how this works without returning anything?  I see from testing that it's altering the original Datetime object, but how does that work if you're not passing by reference, e.g. `&$datetime`

Comment: @StephenR `$datetime` is an object, therefore it is passed by reference by default

Comment: @IterAtor I did not know that. Thanks

Comment: See my answer that handles microseconds, and does a lot more

Answer (score 9):

You can use the ceil, floor and round functions to round a DateTime either up, down or to the nearest minute interval as follows:

```
/**
 * @param \DateTime $dateTime
 * @param int $minuteInterval
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function roundUpToMinuteInterval(\DateTime $dateTime, $minuteInterval = 10)
{
    return $dateTime->setTime(
        $dateTime->format('H'),
        ceil($dateTime->format('i') / $minuteInterval) * $minuteInterval,
        0
    );
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $dateTime
 * @param int $minuteInterval
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function roundDownToMinuteInterval(\DateTime $dateTime, $minuteInterval = 10)
{
    return $dateTime->setTime(
        $dateTime->format('H'),
        floor($dateTime->format('i') / $minuteInterval) * $minuteInterval,
        0
    );
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $dateTime
 * @param int $minuteInterval
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function roundToNearestMinuteInterval(\DateTime $dateTime, $minuteInterval = 10)
{
    return $dateTime->setTime(
        $dateTime->format('H'),
        round($dateTime->format('i') / $minuteInterval) * $minuteInterval,
        0
    );
}
```

Comment: To avoid unexpected changes to the `DateTime` object that was passed to these functions, I suggest to clone the object first, or use `DateTimeImmutable` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: Note this relies on the curious behaviour of "Values exceeding ranges are added to their parent values" in the manual. i.e. setting minute of 72 is converted to 1H + 12mins. (I would have guessed it would be a validation error in a function called "setTime" whereas I could understand it in say "addTime"). The roundUp function in this answer uses this to make setting `current-hour, 60s`  = `hour+1, 0s`, which is needed in the last `$minuteInterval` of each hour to round up and overflow correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I would use timestamps:

```
<?php

function roundTime(\DateTime $datetime, $precision = 10) {

    $ts = $datetime->getTimestamp();
    $s = ($precision * 60);
    $remainder = $ts % $s;

    if ($remainder > 0) {
        $datetime->setTimestamp($ts + $s - $remainder);
    }

    return $datetime;
}

echo roundTime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-03-04 09:00:00'))
    ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// prints: 2016-03-04 09:00:00


echo roundTime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-03-04 09:00:01'))
    ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// prints: 2016-03-04 09:10:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function roundupMinutesFromDatetime(\Datetime $date, $minuteOff = 10)
{
    $string = sprintf(
         "%d minutes %d seconds", 
         $date->format("i") % $minuteOff, 
         $date->format("s")
    );

    return  $date->sub(\DateInterval::createFromDateString($string));
}
```

And the test:

```
public function datetimeProvider()
{
    return array(
        array('2015-01-01 15:16:17', '2015-01-01 15:10:00'),
        array('2015-01-01 09:59:39', '2015-01-01 09:50:00'),
    );
}

/**
 * @dataProvider datetimeProvider
 */
public function testRoundupToMinutesFromDatetime($dateStr, $dateStrAssert)
{
    $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateStr);
    $date = $this->repo->roundupMinutesFromDatetime($date);
    $this->assertEquals($dateStrAssert, $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}
```

have fun.

Comment: This is rounding down to the earlier time

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `strtotime()` function to convert date to timestamp then add or remove minutes for example

```
<?php
$datenow  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
$maketime = strtotime($datenow );

$minutes     = 10;

$after_10min = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", ( $maketime+(60*$minutes) ));
$before_10min = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", ( $maketime-(60*$minutes) ));

echo "Date now : $datenow  <br />";
echo "Date After $minutes min : $after_10min <br />";
echo "Date Before $minutes min : $before_10min <br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy code**

```
<?php
    function next10Minutes()  {
        $time = time() + 600;

        $nextMinutes = floor(date("i", $time) / 10) * 10;

        if ($nextMinutes < 10) {
            $nextMinutes = "00";
        }

        return strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:{$nextMinutes}:00", $time));
    }
```

Comment: This answer is missing its education explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will round (up, down, or just plain round) to an arbitrary number of seconds, minutes, or hours.  Inspired by [@esqilin 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40891513/339440)

Many Bothans died to bring you this information.

PHP 7, though probably not hard to tweak for 5.

```
/**
 * Round $datetime to nearest <$precision> <$unit>s - e.g nearest 10 seconds -- or always up/down per $calc
 * @param \DateTimeInterface $datetime
 * @param int    $precision Round to the nearest number of {$unit}s
 * @param string $unit      'h', 'm', or 's' for Hours, Minutes, or Seconds; or PHP's 'G'/'H' (hours) or 'i' (minutes)
 * @param int    $calc      -1, 0, or 1 = floor, round, or ceiling calculations
 * @return \DateTimeInterface
 * @throws \Exception
 */
function roundTime( \DateTimeInterface $datetime, int $precision = 1, string $unit = 's', int $calc = 0 ) :\DateTimeInterface {
    $offset = $datetime->format( 'Z' );
    $datetime = ( clone $datetime )->modify( "+$offset seconds" );
    switch( $unit ) {   // convert human readable units to PHP DateTime format string
        case 'h':
        case 'H':
            $unit = 'G';
            break;
        case 'm':
            $unit = 'i';
            break;
        // 's' -> 's', no change
    }
    $secs = [ 'G'=>3600, 'i'=>60, 's'=>1 ]; // seconds per hour/minute/second
    if( ! in_array( $unit, array_keys( $secs ) ) ) {
        trigger_error( "Unknown \$unit parameter '$unit' in " . __FUNCTION__ . ". Recognized formats are 'h', 'm', 's', (hours/minutes/seconds), or PHP's 'G', 'H', or 'i'" );
        return $datetime;
    }
    $precision = $precision * $secs[$unit];
    if( -1 === $calc ) {
        $round = 0;
    } elseif( 1 === $calc ) {
        $round = $precision;
    } elseif( 1 == $precision && 's' == $unit ) { // in this -- and only this -- case, we need partial seconds
        $round = ( (int) $datetime->format('v') ) >= 500 ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
        $round = ( ( (int) $datetime->format('U') ) % $precision >= ( $precision/2 ) ) ? $precision : 0;
    }
    $result = $datetime->setTimestamp( ( $precision * floor( $datetime->format('U') / $precision ) ) + $round - $offset );
    return $result;
}
```

In the case proposed in the Question, you would use:

```
$datetime = new DateTime($mysqldata);

echo roundTime( $datetime, 10, 'm', 1 );
```

Answer (score -1):

I overloaded the class and created a method:

```
class MyWish_DateTime extends DateTime {

public function formatToNearRangeMinutesSql($range) {
        $midleRange = $range / 2;

        $minutes = self::format("i");
        $modulo = $minutes % $range;
        if ($modulo > $midleRange) {
            $this->addMinutes($range - $modulo);
        }
        else {
            $this->addMinutes(-$modulo);
        }
        return self::format("H:i");
    }
}
```