# Populate time dropdown in 15 min intervals from now until time X

Tags: php

I have 3 variables of type string that are always changing. Let's say they are currently:

```
$openTime = "10:00 am";
$closeTime = "1:00 pm";
$currentTime = "10:04 am";
```

How can I dynamically generate a dropdown that looks like:

```
<select>
    <option value="10:30 am">10:30 am</option>
    <option value="10:45 am">10:45 am</option>
    ...
    <option value="1:00 pm">1:00 pm</option>
</select>
```

without JS?

Note that the first option isn't 10:15 am because currentTime + 15 minutes = 10:19 am which is past 10:15 am.

Comment: [`DatePeriod`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

Comment: ... combined with [PHP DateTime round up to nearest 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814427/php-datetime-round-up-to-nearest-10-minutes) (I'm sure you can adapt it to 15 minutes) should be all you need